# Shall we build list of bookmarks/sites which would be useful with respect to security and pentesting?

Tags: discussion

We were growing up, every security search updates and solutions were solved by dmz people, Recently buzzed me a idea why not we maintain a community question which would help pentesters to develop their skills.

Like a bookmarks series which was maintained on [google](https://code.google.com/p/pentest-bookmarks/wiki/BookmarksList), shall we maintain our own and maintain it as community wiki?

There were many questions related to this at site under this [tag](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professional-education?sort=votes&pageSize=15), but why not maintain a list of sites which would help the people grow and contribute?

Shall we ask/post a question which would list all sites and ask people to contribute?

Comment: There was something similar, although it now looks inactive: https://code.google.com/p/pentest-bookmarks/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Frankly, no, I don't see the value:

1. Many other places maintain bookmark lists for this purpose
2. It will be difficult to maintain some kind of master list when there are many niches in "pentesting" alone (web, application, network, system, etc.). These niches are served by other sites.
3. Link lists go stale

It's great that you see a need and want to add value to Security.SE! Keep up the good thoughts, but this one just isn't a good fit for us.

You *could* start your own specialized link list on your own site and ask the folks in the DMZ if they have anything to contribute ....

Comment: Github is a better place.